# Own Implementation of Neural Networks heavily under fitting the data

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, data-science-model

I tried to implement a Basic Deep Neural Network Algorithm for a classification problem on my own. I have tried on the iris data set for this test but, my implementation has been giving me very poor results, it's heavily under-fitting the data, the best accuracy I get is 66 % and the least even goes to 0 %, for every run of my algorithm , I get heavily varying results even after I've set a low randomness seed.

I've chosen a tanh activation function, a learning rate of 0.01, a softmax activation for the output layer and a Standard Scalar normalization on the input variables.

So, I'm wondering whether I'm doing any of the math part wrong, or missing any fundamental part of this algorithm, any advice or correction is much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Here's the code:

```
data = load_iris()

X = data.data

y = data.target

class Neural_Network:


def __init__(self, n_hlayers, n_nodes, lr):

    #No. of hidden layers
    self.n_layers = n_hlayers

    #No. of nodes in each of the hidden layer
    self.n_nodes = n_nodes

    #Learning rate of the algorithm
    self.lr = lr

    # Dictionary to hold the node values of all the layers
    self.layers = { }

    # Dictionary to hold the weight values of all the layers
    self.weights = { }

def _softmax(self,values):

    '''Function to perform softmax activation on the node values

    returns probabilities of each feature'''

    exp_scores = np.exp(values)

    probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    return probs

def _derivate_tanh(self,values):

    '''Function that performs derivative of a tanh activation function'''

    #Derivative of tanh is 1 - tanh^2 x
    return (1 - np.power(values, 2))

def fit(self,X,y):

    '''This function constructs a Neural Network with given hyper parameters and then runs it for 

    given no. of epochs. No. of nodes in all the hidden layers are the same for simplicity's sake.

    returns: None / NA'''
    print('Fitting the data ')

    try:
        X = np.array(X)
        y = np.array(y)

    except:
        print('Could not make sense of the inputs')

    # No. of examples and the dimensions of each sample
    self.num_examples, self.features = X.shape

#Setting default layers

    #Input layer
    self.layers['input'] = np.zeros(shape=[1,self.features])

    #Hidden layers
    for i in range(1, (self.n_layers+ 1 )):

        self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)] = np.zeros(shape=[1,self.n_nodes])


    #Output layer
    self.layers['output'] = np.zeros(shape=[1, len(np.unique(y))    ])


#Setting random weights

    for i in range(1, (self.n_layers+2)):

        #Weights for first layer
        if i == 1:
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = np.random.uniform(low=0.1, high = 0.2, size=[self.features, self.n_nodes])

        #Weights for hidden layer
        elif i < (self.n_layers+1): 
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = np.random.uniform(low = 0.1, high = 0.2, size=[self.n_nodes, self.n_nodes])

        #Weights for output layer
        else:
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = np.random.uniform(low = 0.1, high = 0.2, size = [self.n_nodes, len(np.unique(y))])


    #no. of epochs taken from the user
    epochs = int( input('Please choose no.of epochs: '))

    #Standard Scaler to normalize the input data
    S_s = StandardScaler()


    self.X = S_s.fit_transform(X)

    self.y = y.reshape(self.num_examples, 1)


    for ep in range(epochs):


        #Forward propogate on 
        self._Forward_Propogate()

        if ep % 100 == 0:

            #Calculating the accuracy of the predictions
            self. acc = np.sum (self.y.flatten() == np.argmax( self.layers['output'], axis = 1) ) / self.num_examples

            print('Accuracy in epoch ', ep, ' is :', self.acc)

        #Backward propogating
        self._Backward_Propogation()

def _Forward_Propogate(self):

    '''This functions performs forward propogation on the input data through the hidden layers and on the output layer

    activations: tanh for all layers except the output layer

    returns: None/NA.'''

    #Feeding the input layer the normalized inputs
    self.layers['input'] = self.X

    #Forward propogating
    for i in range(1, len(self.layers.keys())):

        #Input Layer dot-product with first set of weights
        if i == 1:
            dp = self.layers['input'].dot(self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)])

            #Storing the result in first hidden layer after performing tanh activation on values
            self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)] = np.tanh(dp)

        #Hidden Layers dot-product with weights for the hidden layer
        elif i != (len(self.layers.keys())-1):

            dp = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)]. dot(self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)])

            #Storing the result in next hidden layer after performing tanh activation on values
            self.layers['layer-1'+ str(i)] = np.tanh(dp)

        # dot-product of last hidden layer with last set of weights    
        else:

            dp = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)].dot(self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)])

            #Storing the result in the output layerafter performing softmax activation on the values
            self.layers['output'] = self._softmax(dp)

def _Backward_Propogation(self):

    '''This function performs back propogation using normal/ naive gradient descent algorithm on the weights of the output layer

    through the hidden layer until the input layer weights

    returns:None/NA'''

    #Dictionary to hold Delta / Error values of each layer
    self.delta = {}

    #Dictionary to hold Gradient / Slope values of each layer
    self.gradients = {}


    #Calculating the error
    error = self.y - self.layers['output']

    #Adjusting weights of the network starting from weights of the output layer
    for i in reversed( range( 1, len(self.weights.keys())  +1   ) ):

        #Adjusting weights for the last layer
        if i == len(self.weights.keys()):


            #Delta for the output layer weights
            self.delta['delta_out'] = error * self.lr

            #Gradient or slope for the last layer's weights
            self.gradients['grad_out'] = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)].T.dot(

                                self.delta['delta_out'])

            #Adjusting the original weights for the output layer
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] - (

                                self.lr * self.gradients['grad_out'])


        #Adjusting weights for last but one layer
        elif i == len(self.weights.keys()) - 1:

            # Delta / error values of the first hidden layer weights seen from the output layer
            self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)] = self.delta['delta_out'].dot( 

                        self.weights['weight-1' + str(i+1)].T ) * self._derivate_tanh(self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)])

            # Gradient / Slope for the weights of the first hidden layer seen from the output layer
            self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i) ] = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)].T.dot( 

                                                        self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)])


            #Adjusting weights of the last but one layer
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] - (

                                                        self.lr * self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)])

        #Adjusting weights for all other hidden layers
        elif i > 1:


            #Delta / Error values for the weights in the hidden layers
            self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)] = self.delta['delta_1' + str(i+1)].dot(

                self.weights['weight-1' + str(i+1)]) * self._derivate_tanh(self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)])

            #Gradient / Slope values for the weights of hidden layers
            self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)] = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)].T.dot(

                self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)])

            #Adjusting weights of the hidden layer
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] - (

                                                self.lr * self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)])

        #Adjusting weights which are matrix-multipled with the input layer   
        else:


            # Delta / Error values for the weights that come after the input layer
            self.delta['delta_inp'] = self.delta['delta_1' + str(i+1)].dot(

                self.weights['weight-1' + str(i+1)]) * self._derivate_tanh( self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)])

            #Gradient / Slope values for the weights that come after the input layer
            self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)] = self.layers['input'].T.dot(self.delta['delta_inp'])

            #Adjusting weights
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] - (

                                                self.lr * self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)])
```

Here's a sample result:

```
ob = Neural_Network(5, 50, 0.01)

 ob.fit(X,y)

 Please choose no.of epochs: 800
Accuracy in epoch  0  is : 0.17333333333333334
Accuracy in epoch  100  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  200  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  300  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  400  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  500  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  600  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  700  is : 0.18
```

Comment: I think that adding a bias node would not make much of difference to the performance. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Bias offset before each activation function is very important, and could help your model here.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thank you for the response. I will try bias offset, but do you think I have any algorithm / logical errors in my program which is causing such poor results ?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to take a decent look, I am on a mobile device, and on holiday for a few days.

Comment: Generally there are mistakes of gradient calculation..Do some gradient checking..If that's not the problem then optimisation...Use better optimisation..Also check the cost accuracy does not indicate wether your algo is correct or not

Comment: @DuttaA Thanks for the response. From my debugging, I figured out that there were no errors with my gradient descent implementation, I'm not entirely sure of what you mean by optimisation in this case, could you please elaborate on that ?

Comment: The node values of my output layer ( probability values from the softmax activation) are really extreme most of the times, they go up to e^-37; I know that, that shouldn't be the case,  when I checked for the weights of the output layer, they were not as extreme , in other words they haven't changed to such a degree that they missed the local minima. So, I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. I would really appreciate if someone can run this program and check for the issues.

Comment: Guys I desperately need to fix this issue, this is an important task for me. Anyone, Please help !

Comment: Optimisation means the optimizer ..U are using gradient descent Probably..Use Adam optimizer instead